# strcpy() does not write new string

Tags: c

In my code, I want to update the contents of global array `data` via a function.  When I call the function, however, the contents of `data` do not change, despite the function calling `strcpy()` to effect that change -- afterward, `data` still contains "prg". **How can I use `strcpy()` or something similar to write a new value to data?**

```
char data[255] = "prg";

void process_tuple(Tuple *t)
{
    //Get key
    int key = t->key;

    //Get integer value, if present
    int value = t->value->int32;

    //Get string value, if present
    char string_value[32];
    strcpy(string_value, t->value->cstring);

    strcpy(data, "prg1212");

    //Decide what to do
    switch(key) {
        case key_0:

        break;
    };
}

static  WeatherAppDataPoint s_data_points[] = 
{
  {
    .city = data,
    .description = "surfboard :)",
    .icon = WEATHER_APP_ICON_GENERIC_WEATHER,
    .current = 110,
    .high = 120,
    .low = 100,
  },   
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem with help from @Blidny and @MikeofSST
It turns out that my code above contained in a file `app_data.c` wasn't running code outside if the functions created in `app_data.h`. I moved my code up into the void where my `temperature` values were formatted and written, and `strcpy()` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking, the program as written will change `data` to `prg1212` if the function is executed. You are either not calling it (bad event hookup, etc), the code as written isn't accurate (partial code that hides the real problem) or evaluating the wrong pointer during debugging (or at the wrong time).

Comment: How would I fix any of these problems? Would you need to see more code? @Blindy

Comment: @AgentSpyname Create a temporary test in your `main()` that (1) uses `printf()` to output the content of `data`, (2) calls `process_tuple()`, (3) uses `printf()` to output the content of `data` again after the call.  **If** the `Tuple* t` you pass is ok and doesn't cause an exception to be thrown, you will see that the value does get changed as expected.

Comment: @MikeofSST I'l give it a try in a bit. Thanks for your help